# Ubuntu18.04 update on cell phone 4G

Tags: networking, upgrade, 4g

I've tried to update my ubuntu desktop (via 'apt-get update') through my mobile's 4G LTE internet broadband. The OS connented and started downloading at first but soon slowed down until it hanged (as if connection was lost). Closing apt-get with Ctrl+C and starting again showed the same result. Reseting the phone's connection didn't help. Is that an issue with 4G on Ubuntu or something related to my internet provider? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If Ubuntu is tethered to your phone, it doesn’t know it’s on 4G. A tethered device will believe it’s on a standard WiFi connection unless explicitly told otherwise by the person operating the machine 

Comment: What would be the difference in regard to system updates?

Answer (score 0):

It' issue in your phone/provider. I update Ubuntu every day via phone. Today all worked.

Comment: Did you set any special configurations? Or just turned on your phone's routing and connected to the system? Is it desktop/PC?